# Errors on https://openmaptiles.org/styles/ pages?

Tags: styles, http-status-code-404, tiles

All kind of broken links here: https://openmaptiles.org/styles/

Comment: So what is your question? Shouldn't you report broken links to the site's webmaster?

Comment: I could not find one. I tried and failed. So any ideas are welcome, the errors are in your face.